# Memory debug option not appearing in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, memory

When trying to do some simple debugging to better understand the code I've written, I tried to use the memory debugging tool however this option did not appear in the menu. I thought this was a pretty simple fix and googled it to no avail. This is odd as when I start debugging the program, the option actually appears. However, when I open "Memory 1" I get "Unavailable when debuggee is running." which is fair enough. Noted that I have ticked both options in Tools > Options (Enable address-level debugging & Show disassembly if source is not available). When I see screenshots of other people's Visual Studio installations I see they have a much larger debug menu. I have attached some screenshots below of a dummy application I have made for demonstration.

I am using: Visual Studio Community 2022 (v.17.5.1)

Screenshot attachments below:

[No memory option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jrYMO.png)

[Memory option appears when debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ckid.png)

[Can't debug memory when debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kkCzB.png)

[Tools > Options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0dDO.png)

If you need anymore information just let me know.

Comment: Set a breakpoint, wait until the program hits that breakpoint, open the memory tab.

Comment: I think you need to be actually debugging to open the memory tab and the execution needs to be stopped at a line to see the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to use the memory debugging tool however this option did not
> appear in the menu

It is by design. You can add memory debugging via Tools-> customize->Add Command-> Debug-> Memory1. But it is only available when debugging.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this in the future > You need to create a breakpoint in the code before you can view the memory (as explained in their comments). You can do this by clicking left of the line number in visual studio (a red dot or breakpoint will appear).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and I remember messing around with settings and the way to get it back is as follows:
Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> Enable address-level debugging (make sure its ticked)

Then while in Debug go to Debug -> Windows and you should see Memory or just go to Command and type memory.